# XCODE 6 (6A313) Compile Error using Outlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using Xcode 6(6A313) to develop an example app (use objective-c), follow the book IOS Programming 4 edition Big Nerd Ranch that is made to work with Xcode 5 however this basic app that has only 2 labels an 2 bottoms get a compile error "**ViewController.xib: error: Illegal Configuration: Launch screens may not have connections.**" when i connect the outlet property with the view controls using Interface Builder.

Anyone has idea whats wrong?

Thank's in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to use a nib or storyboard instead of a launch image is new in Xcode 6, but the view in your launch storyboard can't have outlets.

It seems that you have outlets in the file that is being used for your launch screen. Xcode 6 template projects will now create two files - main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.xib.

Either remove the outlets from LaunchScreen.xib or go to your target and remove the value from the "Launch Screen File" field -

[image: Launch screen setting]

Comment: Right this is the solution. Thank's a lot Paulw11

Comment: @Paulw11: I have the same problem. I have removed the value from "Launch Screen File", but I still get the same error. Must I save some settings after I've removed the value from the field?

Comment: Make sure the cursor had exited that field in the settings and try a clean build

Comment: @Paulw11: I have tried that, But I still get the same error.. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. You are probably trying to add outlets to a .xib file, which is a "Launch Screen" type of file instead of a "View" type of file. It was so in my case. Both of them have the ".xib" extension so I didn't know what was going on. Do the following: File -> New File -> View. Click on created ".xib" file. In the right panel click on "Show identity inspector", set Custom class -> Class to your ViewController. Now you will be able to add outlets without getting errors.

Comment: @koleS Really does not occur errors, but events "overrided" do not work in the custom classes.