# Illegal configuration in Xcode 6.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Im trying to build my project in Xcode, but I get the error message: "Illegal Configuration Launch screens may not have connections".

I have tried to remove the value from the "Launch Screen File"-field, but I get the same error. I've also tried to do a clean build without success.

Anyone who can help me?

[image: mac]

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCODE 6 (6A313) Compile Error using Outlets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944213/xcode-6-6a313-compile-error-using-outlets)

Comment: @ev0lution: It is not a duplicate because I still get the same error after removed the value from the field...

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that you have properties connected to labels in the LaunchScreen file, which is exactly what the error is complaining about and is exactly what the linked question is about. Look at the inspector panel on the right - you need to remove the `answerLabel` and `questionLabel` connections as Michael stated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[LaunchScreen.xib is a new thing that came in with iOS 8 and Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/chapters/AddIcons,Images,andEffects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH19-SW3). Your LaunchScreen.xib can not have any connections.

So what that means is you need to disconnect the "`showQuestion`" and "`showAnswer`" actions and all the outlets you have there.  Those should be defined in a view controller using a different xib.

Comment: Defined in a view controller using a different xib? Must I create a whole new xib?

Comment: Yes. But then you can just cut and paste your buttons and bells & whistles from the launch screen (which is only supposed to have a single root view or view controller that *doesn't update*) and you can paste it into the new xib file.

Comment: Okey. Thank you. Can you recommend a book about IOS programming? I currently use The Big Nerd Ranch, but that book is outdated.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the problems with iOS tutorial books. As good as The Big Nerd Ranch book is, Apple is determined to unleash and release dramatic changes to iOS developers each and every year (iOS 6 to iOS 7 to iOS 8, Xcode 3 to Xcode 4 to Xcode 6, etc.).

Comment: I've just removed the outlets(connections) in my Launchscreen.xib, and the compiling worked. But how do I do the connections with the outlets in the new .xib-file?

Comment: just create a new view controller with a new xib file and go drop your outlets and your buttons in there and start coding from that point.

Comment: Okey. In the book, they are using xcode 5.0.2. If I download that version and develop apps, can I run the apps on the latest version of IOS 8 and on the latest iphone?

Answer (score 0):

Going thru the big nerd ranch as well with Xcode 6,

To complete the previous answer, the other .xib file is displayed as "Main.storyboard" in the project hierarchy.

"Main.storyboard" is where one needs to implement the "label" and "button" in drag and drop mode for the demo project, and then it is possible to connect them with the methods created in file "ViewController.m".

Then you'll probably have another issue with the "initWithNibName" not loading when the app is launched. But I haven't solved that one yet.